# How to use CTEs with update/delete on SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, common-table-expression

SQLite now has CTEs, and the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) says you can use it with insert, update and delete queries -- but only gives examples of select statements.

I can figure out how CTEs apply to inserts, via insert-select; but how can we use them in update or delete, where there is no from-clause?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CTEs can be used in subqueries:

```
WITH NewNames(ID, Name) AS (...)
UPDATE MyTable
SET Name = (SELECT Name
            FROM NewNames
            WHERE ID = MyTable.ID);

WITH IDsToDelete AS (...)
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN IDsToDelete;
```

Comment: Is there really no better way to use CTEs?

Answer (score 7):

Another slightly more concise way of using CTE in SQlite 3.15.0 and up.

```sql
WITH t (id, name, nickname) AS (VALUES (1, "bob", "bobby"), (2, "john", "johnny"))
UPDATE user
SET (name, nickname) = (
    SELECT name, nickname
    FROM t WHERE user.id = t.id
)
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t)
```

Works great as a bulk update!