# Recursive update in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion

I have table `objs`, that contains info about files and dirs.
Each record has rows

```
id, fileSize, parentID, dirSize.
```

Each (but not first record) of record has parentID, that equal to id of parent directory.

I want to count recursively sizes of each directory.

Simple solution, without recursive and based on files and dirs paths is

```
   update objs set dirSize= (
select sum(b.fileSize) from objs b where b.fullPath like objs.fullPath||'\%' and b.isDir=0) 
where isDir=1
```

I want to rewrite it to recursive method, but I stucked on

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  works_for_alice(n, m) AS (
    select id, fileSize from objs where id=9
    UNION
    SELECT a.id, a.fileSize FROM objs a, works_for_alice b
     WHERE a.parentID=b.n 
  )
SELECT sum(m)  FROM  works_for_alice
```

I can't understand, how to apply this select

```
SELECT sum(m)  FROM  works_for_alice
```

to the update of the `objs` table and how to change value of the id in the

```
select id, fileSize from objs where id=**9**
```

in the `WITH`, to pass into this selector value of the id of the updating row in update statement...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with this query, that inspired by post [sqlite CTE with UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983416/sqlite-cte-with-update) and sqlite `with` documentation https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html :

```
update objs set dirSize = 0;
update objs set dirSize = (
            WITH RECURSIVE
  works_for_alice(n, m) AS(
   select objs.id, 0
    UNION all
    SELECT a.id, a.fileSize FROM objs a, works_for_alice b
     WHERE a.parentID = b.n
  )
SELECT sum(m)  FROM works_for_alice
)
```

Comment: `works_for_alice` is *not* an SQL keyword that you would have to adopt unchanged, and `n`/`m` aren't good names either.

Comment: I know, it's just experimental code snippet it was copy-pasted and re-written in 3 hour of deep night :)...